# Где границы деепричастного оборота?

Tags: недопустимая-метка, деепричастный-оборот

Проводя почти всё своё время неразлучно с матерью, потому что я и писал и читал в её отдельной горнице, где обыкновенно и спал, — там стояла моя кроватка и там был мой дом, — я менее играл с сестрицей, реже виделся с ней (Акс.) 
— запятая перед первым тире закрывает придаточную часть, запятая перед вторым тире закрывает деепричастную конструкцию;

Вопрос: в учебнике пишется, что запятая перед вторым тире закрывает деепричастную конструкцию. Я не пойму: разве не запятая после слова *матерью* закрывает деепричастную конструкцию? Выходит, что *Проводя почти всё своё время неразлучно с матерью, потому что я и писал и читал в её отдельной горнице, где обыкновенно и спал,* - это все деепричастный оборот? Но если это все входит в деепричастный оборот,то запятая после *спал* не может одновременно закрывать и деепричастный оборот и придаточную часть *где обыкновенно и спал*?

Answer (score 1):

Все правильно. Здесь в деепричастном обороте присутствует вставная конструкция "потому что я и писал и читал в её отдельной горнице, где обыкновенно и спал, — там стояла моя кроватка и там был мой дом".  Запятая  перед первым тире закрывает придаточную часть, запятая перед вторым тире закрывает деепричастную конструкцию. Вставные конструкции, выражая дополнительные сообщения, требуют более значительного выделения в составе предложения, нежели вводные конструкции, как правило, заключающие в себе отношение к высказанному, его оценку. Именно эта смысловая самостоятельность вставных конструкций объясняет необходимость использования для их выделения скобок и тире.Однако в зависимости от синтаксической структуры основного предложения и вставной конструкции на месте «разрыва», помимо тире, могут быть еще запятые, как, например, в вашем примере.

Doom, вот ссылка: http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=383.P5q2mfdpuWCO3esgAv0zHK8dY7XttlbPJae0L8lmGFhWRXTAkp0F9201KKAwE_0glHm2QnFL4jDYwfkI_AQFXAPxbnDfItMOduRXwsjg3q9Hoc8uzr4Rq6FfoD_ryMlfmb55eUn6Wy2UkLTtmnu0rIKqUvhLo6JfBrl-IvFV1L-V0aDTpNNissKqGkpJsSfDepLhTXksQbbxYqKXYWSW7GW688HZCh8l8TD0g_7qn10nNhQ7SVwYZUexWacgYQOiyDzbmwzu_PmAToPJv5zphSRk6LQe4NPtaqHuYdzAvcKPCtJEAfJcnua06M_NRdGR3AjihQ3oO_27ikcYCsv9BGTjIPNPO0o3SgQiUwS3yVpUiX6SpFUOaNr6WCgPq4QgAXsfPLEru28s0_qIX45Sxw.81530a5a3127da5fb04a2ed61425b24bf6098e52&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9XsGes-COYeAtjuEaMUoBSHP2gxXC4630Mztqhj4v-ZuGDY04GB8Kxku4XYH7t4tU7APulXBMWX2oX40SVo_0NA2NszBHsun14az5SVht8ii8591Ou3Pl2rSGtq-0MTVAThD-sx0AEp2GuCgrVlX1NlEwdnierCWaZflVJgSQWTY0nHS2sExWI0jz9ijlJjszsOkXYed_Fv-Uw&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1Ldmtxck01b09icEh6NDRmcjZGNmVseWNaeWtoQktZQ1U3cjFOeTltZjJvNkpKZXVIZk0tYkNicXdtckdhRGhXQkdWOXJ6QXFLellGeVZGU2lUbjdqS1R2bzFQblhxelpzd3ItdU1vbEhvVzdrQ0V5TVh4MTE3Q1RJb0hpajVvTUJ3SzhUSlNucWZ6UTJ3UUtxcExjNWtNMVgwVHRqYU5ONUhoNjU2ZHBBNnVOVUMy&b64e=2&sign=b081f09b07246bcb639e869a676eb91b&keyno=0&l10n=ru . Там, кстати(на второй странице), есть и ваш пример.

Comment: Серж, а Вы считаете, что это всё - вставная конструкция? Кажется, вставки не имеют синтаксической союзной связи с предложением или членами предложения, но относятся к ним только по смыслу. А у нас союз ПОТОМУ ЧТО. И выделяются вставки обычно с помощью тире  и скобок. У Вас есть информация об особом оформлении вставных конструкций?

Answer (score 1):

ПРОВОДЯ ПОЧТИ ВСЁ СВОЁ ВРЕМЯ НЕРАЗЛУЧНО С МАТЕРЬЮ, потому что я и писал и читал в её отдельной горнице, где обыкновенно и спал, — там стояла моя кроватка и там был мой дом, — Я МЕНЕЕ ИГРАЛ С СЕСТРИЦЕЙ, РЕЖЕ ВИДЕЛСЯ С НЕЙ.

Старшей конструкцией является простое предложение, осложненное деепричастным оборотом. К деепричастному обороту относится  сложная конструкция:  два придаточных с последовательным подчинением (придаточное причины и придаточное определительное), а  к придаточному причины относится вставка.

Интонация выражает структуру простого  осложненного предложения, а оба придаточных со вставкой   читаются как единая вставная конструкция второго плана.

Тогда с запятыми всё в порядке.

Comment: К деепричастному обороту относится сложная конструкция: два придаточных с последовательным подчинением (придаточное причины и придаточное определительное. Значит, эти придаточные не входят в деепричастный оборот. Но этот пример я взяла из Розенталя:

4) и перед первым и перед вторым тире ставятся запятые по условиям текста: – запятая перед первым тире закрывает придаточную часть, запятая перед вторым тире закрывает деепричастную конструкцию;
Тогда перед вторым тире не должна быть запятая, так как, судя по вашему ответу, дееприч. обор. закрывает запятая после "матерью"?

Comment: Розенталь под деепричастной конструкцией понимает деепричастный оборот и придаточные предложения, которые отнесены к обороту, но в его состав не входят. Похожие примеры: Устав, потому что было поздно, они наконец разошлись. Сказав, что уже  поздно, она ушла.